# Can I use apothecaries to reroll lasting injuries?

Tags: blood-bowl

In Blood Bowl 2020, when you roll on the casualty table and get a lasting injury, and use an apothecary, can you reroll the the lasting injury?

Under patching up casualties, the rules state:

> The coach on the opposing team rolls again on the casualty table, giving two possible outcomes.

Supposing that both d16 are rolled, and both come up lasting injury - would a d6 be rolled for both, or would lasting injury be selected and then a single d6 be rolled?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You use the apothecary immediately after the casualty roll, but the d6 for a characteristic reduction seems to be part of that roll.

> The coach of the opposing team rolls again on the Casualty table, giving two possible outcomes. You may choose which result is applied to your player.

It says "outcomes" which means what will happen to the player; a reduction in strength is a different outcome to a reduction in agility, so you get to choose.

There's no official FAQ specifically mentioning this, but we can see that this is how it's been implemented digitally for other versions. For example, this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/bloodbowl/comments/qlrs8q/bb2_does_anyone_else_regret_buying_apothecary/) discusses the videogame Blood Bowl 2 offering the players the choice between a stat loss and death. While the tables are different, it seems like the lasting injury result was mainly to condense the table, so I would assume it works the same way unless it mentioned otherwise.